# How to make a popup window that is read and write?

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to make a popup window, but how do I make it to accept keystrokes.  Mine seems to open up in a readonly mode...  Here is the code I used

```
window.open('http://fous.com/testfile.html','popup','width=800,height=1000,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');
```

Comment: what do you mean by keystrokes ?

Comment: I have input tags in that window and want to gather data from the user.  This is not just for doings ads.

Comment: The window does come up, but I cannot enter anything into the input textboxes...

Comment: If I call up a regular browser window data can be entered all you want.

Comment: Do you have a demo link? Is this really the URL you wanted > http://fous.com/testfile.html

Comment: It is in my private server...  The cursor will not sit in focus in any of the textboxes...

Comment: Do the popup windows even have a read/write option???

Answer (score 0):

The combination of options seems to lockup the window when using:

```
window.open('http://fous.com/testfile.html', 'popup','width=800,height=1000,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');
```

This seems to give the desireable result.

```
myWindow=window.open('http://fous.com/testfile.html','','width=800,height=1000', top=0,left=0,scrollbars=0)
```